# Allocate memory for polymorphic object with allocator

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

Very simple question - how to allocate and deallocate memory via allocator, for polymorphic object? Okay, allocate memory is not a big problem:

```
SomeAllocator::rebind<Child>::other allocator;
Parent*pointer=allocator.allocate(1);
new(pointer) Child;
```

For deallocate this memory, I should call `SomeAllocator::rebind<Child>::other::deallocate`... Or `SomeAllocator::rebind<GrandChild>::other::deallocate`? It's polymorphic object and I don't know what exactly type he have. So, I don't know what allocator I must call. I can imagine some tricks. For example - allocate and deallocate memory via `std::allocator<char>().allocate(sizeof(ObjectType))` and `std::allocator<char>().deallocate((char*)pointer,sizeof(ObjectType))`. But this trick throw away any potential optimizations like "this allocator use pool of Child objects". Plus, in polymorphic object, I don't know sizeof for this object. So, I must save this size somewhere. After allocate implementation already save it (of course, only in 99% cases, where allocate() - just redirect to malloc, lol). It don't see this as very good practice. Also, I can use virtual functions like:

```
virtual void Child::destroy(){
    ~Child();
    SomeAllocator::rebind<Child>::other().deallocate(this,1);
}
```

But it's also not very good idea, because I must duplicate this code in all derivate classes.

So, what is best decision for allocate and deallocate memory for polymorphic object vis allocators?
PS Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: Why would you call deallocate for `GrandChild` when you have a `Child` object? You did `new(pointer) Child;` so you know the type.

Comment: I have `Parent*pointer`. Yes, in this example I kno that `Parent*pointer` pointed to Child object. But in real code I don't kno what exactly object I have. I just know that this object is derived from Parent.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but `dynamic_cast<void*>(foo)` will return a `void*` pointer to the most-derived type of the polymorphic object pointed to by `foo`. So if you have a `Parent *foo;` that actually points to a `GrandChild gc;` then [`dynamic_cast<void *>(foo) == &gc`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a928bd2350c35046). This at least gives you a pointer to the start of the real object. You might be able to allocate a container object that contains the real object and an `std::function` to invoke the deallocator, and use `offsetof()` to get from the base obj to the container obj.

Answer (score 1):

I would think about using a concept/model idiom.

The concept defines the concepts (services) available on the common interface, the model describes the implementation of handling the allocator conversion and storage.

e.g.:

```
#include <memory>

struct I
{
    virtual ~I() = default;
};

struct A : I
{
    int x, y, z;
};

struct B : I
{
    int a, b, c, x, y, z;
};

template<class T> struct tag {};

struct IPtr
{
    struct concept
    {
        template<class T> void construct(void * addr)
        {
            ptr_ = new (addr) T ();
        }


        virtual void dealloc() = 0;

        void destroy() 
        { 
            ptr_->~I(); 
            dealloc();
        }

        void* mem_ = nullptr;
        I* ptr_ = nullptr;
    };

    template<class T, class Allocator>
    struct model : concept
    {
        model(Allocator alloc) 
        : alloc_(alloc) 
        {
            using A2 = typename Allocator::template rebind<T>::other;
            auto a2 = A2(alloc_);
            mem_ = a2.allocate(1);
            ptr_ = new (mem_) T ();
        }

        virtual void dealloc() override
        {
            using A2 = typename Allocator::template rebind<T>::other;
            auto a2 = A2(alloc_);
            a2.deallocate(reinterpret_cast<typename A2::pointer>(mem_), 1);
        }

        Allocator alloc_;
    };

    template<class T, class Allocator>
    IPtr(tag<T>, Allocator alloc)
    : impl_(new model<T, Allocator>(alloc))
    {

    }

    IPtr(IPtr&& r) 
    : impl_(r.impl_)
    {
        r.impl_ = nullptr;
    }

    ~IPtr()
    {
        if (impl_) {
            impl_->destroy();
            delete impl_;
        }
    }

private:
    concept* impl_;

};


int main()
{
    auto alloc = std::allocator<int>();
    auto a = IPtr(tag<A>(), alloc);
    auto b = IPtr(tag<B>(), alloc);

    a;
    b;
}
```

Comment: Em... `impl_(new model<T, Allocator>(alloc))` return us to begin - how allocate memory for polymorphic object "concept"? Of course without call of global operator new. In other case we don't need allocators from the start.

Comment: @Aso. The model is a model of an object manager. If you want it to handle the allocation of itself you can create it manually with a call to allocate. It can destroy itself because it has an allocator.

Comment: Yes, I missing that concept object already have allocator and can destroy itself, Thanks, this is complicated, but interested idea.